# Grouping and Summing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column contains `years` and the second column contain `value`. I want to group a certain year and change it to one name for that group and add all the corresponding values.

For example, below is the small dataset

```
years    value
1950      3
1951      1
1952      2
1961      4
1964      10
1970      34
```

The output should look like

```
years    value
1950's     6
1960's     14
1970's     34
```

I am trying this in Python using `pandas` and tried a lot many ways, converting to dict or for loop and but every time I was not able to achieve as desired. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integer division, multiple `10`, cast to string and add `s` and use this Series for aggregating `sum`:

```
y = ((df['years'] // 10) * 10).astype(str) + 's'

df = df.groupby(y)['value'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   years  value
0  1950s      6
1  1960s     14
2  1970s     34
```

**Detail**:

```
print (y)
0    1950s
1    1950s
2    1950s
3    1960s
4    1960s
5    1970s
Name: years, dtype: object
```

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I tried the floor division and multiplication ((trial['years']//10)*10).astype(str) + 's' but it gave an error as:  unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @ShubhamRawlani - How working `y = ((df['years'].astype(int) // 10) * 10).astype(str) + 's'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) to create groups and then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['year'] = pd.cut(df['year'], bins=[1949,1959,1969,1979], labels=['1950s','1960s','1970s'])

print(df.groupby('year')['value'].sum().reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   year  value                                                                                                                       
0  1950s      6                                                                                                                       
1  1960s     14                                                                                                                       
2  1970s     34
```